# Where can I get free XNA compatible FBX Models from?

Tags: graphics, xna, models, fbx

I'm trying to find some free XNA friendly FBX Models to use in my test application. I found some 3DS models and converted them to FBX and tried using them, but I just see some 'lines' on the screen .. I know I may have to scale/translate them, but I tried doing this and nothing worked ... Some models won't show anything at all, not even the line artifacts ..

Any ideas where I can get fairly simply FBX models from which can be used in XNA 3.1 ?

Also, there are some models I saw which contain mutiple FBX files .. I dont want these as they require more complexity .. Right now I'm just looking for models contained within one FBX file ..

Answer (score 0):

http://turbosquid.com is a great place to get some free models, but the paid ones are always better.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mixamo.com/ also has some free character models. No animations though, unless you pay. However, if you're looking for animations, Carnegie mellon university has a whole slew of motion-capture files for free. You'd have to re-rig the character yourself using 3ds max or whatever 3D program you like to use, so that they use "biped" instead of bones, that's the only way to use BVH. 
Motion capture BVH files can be found here: https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion

Comment: Great site... but I didn't see any terrain models?